Калькулятор долго думает в телеграмм боте
#Калькулятор
    if message.text =='Калькулятор':

        if value_colculeter=='':   
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '0',reply_markup=markup_kalkulytor)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,value_colculeter,reply_markup=markup_kalkulytor)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_func(query):
    global value_colculeter, old_value_colculetr
    data_colulater=query.data
    if data_colulater=='C':
        value_colculeter=''
    elif data_colulater=='=':
        value_colculeter=str(eval(value_colculeter))
    elif data_colulater =='<=':
        value_colculeter=''
    else:
        value_colculeter += data_colulater
    if value_colculeter != old_value_colculetr:
        if value_colculeter=='':
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=query.message.chat.id,message_id=query.message.message_id, text='0', reply_markup=markup_kalkulytor)
        else:
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=query.message.chat.id,message_id=query.message.message_id, text=value_colculeter, reply_markup=markup_kalkulytor)
    old_value_colculetr=value_colculeter

Все работает вроде правильно, но зависает, если быстро вводить цифры в калькулятор.
Также при зависании есть шанс, что бот прекратит свою работу.
Подскажите, можно ли как-то ускорить его работу?

Сделать его асинхронным и он будет лучше работать.

Подскажите, как это должно выглядеть)
